# Some of the textures and materials resets while importing models from maya autodesk to unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, maya, autodesk

I am somewhat beginner to Unity3d and an absolute beginner in Maya modelling.
I created a room model in Maya Autodesk 2017 student version referring one youtube tutorial.
And made an attempt to import .ma file in Unity3D.
But when I import it some materials are not visible in unity.
To be precise blinn is visible but material created by Lambert or by using images aren't.
It seems like unity can't recognise this material.
I tried to google it. But there they show something like converting to .fbx file or exporting materials. But I don't see .fbx option in save scene and Maya Autodesk isn't allowing me to export material as it is student version.
Maya is just allowing me to save scenes in .ma and .mb format.
Am I missing something while importing? and if not then is there any way I can use exact models that I created in Maya Autodesk in unity3D.

**edit:**
I am attaching sample images from unity3D and Maya Autodesk.

Image From Maya Autodesk:
[image: Thank you.]
Image from Unity3D:
[image]
Here it is clear that when the image of earth is used to create material, Unity3D is unable to render it.
Also, I noticed that in Maya Autodesk I have to turn texture button on to see the texture of earth.
Do unity have any such setting that prevents it from displaying texture from other software?

Comment: Only thing what you need is correct unwrapping. It is better to create material in Unity. Also I suggest to take a look at Blender modeling software. It can export as FBX and is opensource.

Comment: @Matthew thank you for the suggestion.Currently, I am trying to find the way around this problem because I am now quite familiar with Maya environment.But surely if I didn't find any legal solution I will switch to Blender.

Comment: Can you show the before and after picture? I mean picture of the models in Maya and when imported into Unity. I might be able to help.

Comment: @Programmer I messed up with some of the previous texture and model arrangement. So I changed the images in question as per your requirement.Please have a look at edits.Thank you

Comment: What are you exporting it as? It looks like you are simple missing the Texture. Select the material in Unity then put the Texture to it.

Comment: @Programmer I am exporting that file as .mb .As I mentioned before I can only export file in .mb or .ma format.About creating material in unity, which is a good solution but in unity I didn't find a way to create textures like giving rocky effect on just certain part of the component for e.g. giving that effect on just bottom of the pillar to indicate dirt accumulation while leaving the upper part of the pillar as it is.For time being I will continue creating materials in unity.

Comment: I don't think you understand how to use Maya that well. There is albedo, occlusion and normal maps which are the most used maps. If you use more than one material and shader in Maya, you have to bake it. Make sure to bake them into these maps. When you import the model into Unity, there should be a material from Maya. All you have to do is plug in the textures that have been baked into the right slot in the Material in Unity. That's it. I don't think writing here will help so I suggest you take a course or watch some youtube videos about this.

Comment: @Programmer yes I am a beginner and I do understand that everything can't be explained right here.Thanks for suggesting baking.